# Changing the argument of a function

Tags: filters, child-theme

This is part of a function in Woocommerce:

```
    function woocommerce_breadcrumb( $args = array() ) {
        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', array(
            'delimiter'   => '&nbsp;&#47;&nbsp;',
            'wrap_before' => '<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb">',
             'wrap_after'  => '</nav>',
            'before'      => '',
            'after'       => '',
            'home'        => _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ),
        ) ) );

       //blah blah blah

   }
```

I am wondering how I can change the "wrap_before" in my child-theme without touching the function itself. First I though it must be with apply_filter but it didn't look right.

I am certain that this question has been asked many times but I couldn't find the relevant keywords for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: (add to *functions.php* of your theme)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'wpse_woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults' );
function wpse_woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults( $args ) {
    $args['wrap_before'] = '<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb my-class">';
    $args['wrap_after'] = '</nav>';

    return $args;
}
```

Or, copy:

*wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/global/breadcrumb.php*

to

<strike>*wp-content/**themes/your-theme**/templates/global/breadcrumb.php*</strike>

**UPDATE:** This is the correct path and not above: (*thanks @mmm*)

*wp-content/**themes/your-theme/woocommerce**/global/breadcrumb.php*

and change the `echo $wrap_before;` and `echo $wrap_after;` to your liking..

Reference: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: i think that the file must go in `wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php` and not `.../templates/...`